# How to remount a device in read-write mode, which is already mounted read-only?

Tags: linux, mount

I am thinking to do such thing, but I am not aware for such conditions. So, I wanted to know what will happen if I remount.

Comment: your linux installation probably does a remount in read-write mode at every boot already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /Mountedpartition
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on **why** the filesystem is in read-only mode.

If the filesystem has detected errors indicating potential filesystem corruption, the default behavior is to go to read-only mode to minimize the danger of corrupting more data. This situation is usually very recognizable by the spew of error messages it causes in `dmesg` listing and/or system logs.

In that case, attempts to remount the filesystem read-write will either be refused outright with a message saying "filesystem needs checking" or similar, or the filesystem will switch to read-write mode but will fall back to read-only as soon as it encounters the same error again, depending on the specific filesystem driver in question. The right way to fix these types of situations is to take the time to take an extra backup, unmount the filesystem and run a filesystem check on it.

If the filesystem is clean of errors but has been intentionally mounted read-only, generally there should be no problem remounting it read-write.

But if you are sharing a single block device to two or more computers using iSCSI, FibreChannel or similar SAN solutions, you should be aware that regular filesystems don't allow simultaneous use by multiple computers. Only specialized *cluster filesystems* can do that. Because of how disk caching works, a regular non-cluster filesystem will very rapidly get corrupted if accessed on two computers simultaneously. This does not apply to NAS-type sharing solutions, as the thing being shared is a network service designed for such sharing, rather than a raw disk/LUN.